# In GameMaker how to check if instance is a given object?

Tags: game-maker, gameobject

Let's say, I have three objects: `obj_square`, `obj_circle` and `obj_triangle`.

Instances of all three types of objects exists in the room and call the same script: `scr_test`.

Inside of this script, how can I check instance of which object is calling it?

Pseudocode:

```
if(self is instanceof(obj_circle))
{
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`object_index`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20properties/object_index.html)

> This read only variable returns the index of the object that the instance has been created from.

So your code would read:

```
if(object_index == obj_square) {
    // ...
}
```